# using NSE on spread_ in R tidyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Using the following dataset:

```
temp <- structure(list(
  GENDER = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                     .Label = c("F", "M"), 
                     class = "factor"), 
  EVERFSM_6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
  `0001` = c(0, 11, 22, 33, 33, 55, 66, 77, 88, 0), 
  n = c(20L, 13L, 4L, 13L, 36L, 94L, 28L, 50L, 27L, 1L)), 
  .Names = c("GENDER", "EVERFSM_6", "0001", "n"), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

And I'm trying to perform the following [spread_](http://search.r-project.org/library/tidyr/html/spread_.html) operation to summarise the data:

```
DiscID <- "0001"
colID <- as.name(DiscID)
cols <- c("GENDER", colID, "n")

gender_results <- temp %>%
  select_(.dots=cols) %>%
  group_by_(.dots=cols[1:2]) %>%
  summarise(gender_n = sum(n)) %>% 
  spread_(paste0("`",DiscID,"`"), "gender_n") %>%
  rename(type = GENDER)
```

But it says:

```
Error: Key column '`0001`' does not exist in input.
```

I'm having to use the _ version of select_, group_by_ and spread_ as I am using a variable to refer to column names. The desired output is below, achievable by using the hard coded:

```
spread(`0001`, gender_n) %>%

    type     0    11    22    33    55    66    77    88
  (fctr) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int)
1      F    20    13     4    36    94    28    NA    NA
2      M     1    NA    NA    13    NA    NA    50    27
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your `DiscID` is already ok for use with `spread_`, no need to `paste`. does this help?

```
cols <- c("GENDER", colID, "n")
gender_results <- temp %>%
  select_(.dots=cols) %>%
  group_by_(.dots=cols[1:2]) %>%
  summarise(gender_n = sum(n)) %>% 
  spread_(DiscID, "gender_n") %>%
  rename(type = GENDER)
```

alternatively:

```
cols <- list(~GENDER, colID, ~n)
gender_results <- temp %>%
  select_(.dots=cols) %>%
  group_by_(.dots=cols[1:2]) %>%
  summarise(gender_n = sum(n)) %>% 
  spread_(DiscID, "gender_n") %>%
  rename(type = GENDER)
```

From the [NSE vignette in dplyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html)

Comment: it does! But now I'm confused why spread_ accepts this, but select_ and group_by_ don't. Thanks!

Comment: to use such a blend of variables, `cols` may be passed as `list(~GENDER, colID, ~n)` instead (from the NSE vignette in dplyr)